# ¿Como establecer una condicion WHERE al resultado de un COUNT en OracleSQL?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

quisiera que me mostrara al ejecutar en "TOTAL_VENTAS" solo los resultados que son menores a 2

```
    select x.numrut as "RUT EMPLEADO", x.pnombre ||' '|| x.appaterno as "NOMBRE 
    EMPLEADO", count( z.monto_total) as TOTAL_VENTAS
    from empleado x full join ventas z
    on z.id_empleado=x.id_empleado
    where z.monto_total<2
    group by x.appaterno, x.numrut, x.pnombre
    order by TOTAL_VENTAS asc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los valores agregados (`sum()`, `count()`, `avg()`, etc) se filtran en la cláusula `HAVING`, no en `WHERE`:

```sql
select x.numrut as "RUT EMPLEADO",
    x.pnombre ||' '|| x.appaterno as "NOMBRE EMPLEADO",
    count(z.monto_total) as TOTAL_VENTAS
from empleado x full join ventas z
    on z.id_empleado=x.id_empleado
group by x.appaterno, x.numrut, x.pnombre
having TOTAL_VENTAS < 2
order by TOTAL_VENTAS asc;
```

La cláusula `WHERE` te va a filtrar qué filas de la tabla original quieres que se tengan en cuenta para hacer lo que quieras hacer.

Luego, se agruparán esas filas por lo que hayas puesto en la cláusula `GROUP BY`.

Después se realizarán los cálculos de las funciones de agregación (sum, avg, etc).

Por último, se filtrarán esas nuevas filas agregadas por lo que hayas puesto en la cláusula `HAVING`.